# TICK-STACK Table view format in Chronograf Dashboard

Tags: time-series, influxdb, telegraf, chronograf

I am new to TICK Stack and exploring the features.
I am stuck in dashboard section of Chronograf.

In Chronograf dashboard I am trying to display details log in Table format view not in line, bar graph.

SO in Chronograf -> Data Explorer I got the data in table format as shown in picture.

**But How Can We display the same query output in table format in Chronograf-> Dashboard.**

Details:
TICK-STACK: Version 1.3
(upgrading to 1.4.4.2 for chronograf dashboard.)
[image]

Comment: which version of Chronograf supports the " Dashboard Table Graph Format"   Ref: [ "https://github.com/influxdata/chronograf/issues/1686"]

Comment: Hi all, I am moving towards "GRAFANA" integrated with GRAFANA. "http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/influxdb/", GRAFANA by default have the table view dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to build dashboard cells using the table is new in Chronograf 1.5 (released yesterday). I would check out [this press release](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/chronograf-1-5-and-kapacitor-1-5-released/) for all the details, but you can scroll through your data in the tables now, scan the text, and hide and show columns as needed.

Comment: Yes ! just pulled docker container for the Chronograf 1.5 finally table view is available int Chronograf,  till now I was using Grafana dashboard.